Mine are a bit tight from when I did them this morning
A group of children on TV are playing with their shoelaces, learning how to tie etc. In a scene, they are trying to undo shoelaces quickly, and one of them says:
Mine are a bit tight from when I did them this morning. CBEEBIES tweenies (see:1:50-1:55) (I wrote it from the subtitles, which seem correct but still I can't be 100% sure as a non-native speaker)
Firstly, I didn't quite grasp the relation between tying them in the morning and laces being tight now. Having tied them in the morning can't be a reason for them being tight now, can it?
Secondly, why is there a "from when" in the sentence? Does she say it to imply "Her shoelaces are not so tight when tied by someone else."?
Regards,


Mine are a bit tight from when (the moment) I tied them [until now].

The shoelaces have been tied tightly since they were tied in the morning [by the child].
From gives the starting point of an action or situation, for example;

Starting from Monday I'm taking up jogging.
The bank manager will be able to see you from Tuesday.

Usually when we use from we mention a time span, e.g:

The banks are open Mondays to Fridays from 08.30 to 17.00 (from 8.30am to 5.00pm)


I understand. "from" means "since" in that sentence. But she should have put it in a present perfect tense, shouldn't she? For instance, wouldn't this have been better if she had said:  "Mine have been a bit tight since the morning when I tied them."

@Yunus  It is grammatical though, just slightly informal, which is wholly appropriate for that show. "Mine have been tight since [I tied them] this morning" is how I might phrase it.

She means that her laces are tight as a result of the way she tied them when she put her shoes on in the morning. Evidently they haven't worked loose at all.

By saying "....from when I did them in the morning", does she mean ".....because when I did them in the morning? I thought it meant ".......since when I did them in the morning."

'Because when I did them' doesn't make sense. She means 'because of the way I tied them' , though obviously they have also remained tied tightly since the morning.
